# Adding Asynctask functionality?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have an activity where I will be getting information from an API Call. I am aware of the main thread in case of android and know that I shouldn't overload it. I tried using a thread but I think for the complexity of the app, Asynctask will be the best way to go.

I am currently using `Thread().run()` but it still returns 'Skipping x frames, too much work in the main thread'. I want to know how I can add the Asynctask class to my app for better performance. My activity uses ExpandableListView.

Home.java:

```
public class Home extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home_act);
    init();

}

void init() {
    findViews();
    changeFont();
    clickListeners();
    assignConditions("category", "all", "1");
    categoryAllApiCall();
}

void categoryAllApiCall() {
    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(base_url).setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL).build();
    final Category_All category_all = restAdapter.create(Category_All.class);
    category_all.getFeed(file, operation_condition, all_condition, max_depth_condition, new Callback<CategoryPojo>() {
        @Override
        public void success(CategoryPojo categoryPojo, Response response) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            final CategoryPojo category = categoryPojo;
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    category_id = Arrays.copyOf(category.getCategoryId(), category.getCategoryId().length);
                    category_name = Arrays.copyOf(category.getCategoryName(), category.getCategoryName().length);
                    parent_id = Arrays.copyOf(category.getParentId(), category.getParentId().length);
                }
            }).run();
            prepareListData();
            setAdapter();
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            tv_title_header.setText(error.getMessage());
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

}

private void prepareListData() {
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    int count = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < category_id.length; i++) {
        List<String> child = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (parent_id[i].equals("0")) {
            count++;
            listDataHeader.add(category_name[i]);
            for (int j = 0; j < category_id.length; j++) {
                if (parent_id[j].equals(category_id[i])) {
                    child.add(category_name[j]);

                }
            }
            listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(count), child);
        }
    }
}

void setAdapter() {
    elv_home_body_lay.setAdapter(new HomeExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild));
    elv_home_body_lay.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
        int previousGroup = -1;

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            if (groupPosition != previousGroup) {
                elv_home_body_lay.collapseGroup(previousGroup);
            }
            previousGroup = groupPosition;
        }
    });

    elv_home_body_lay.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this, ProductListing.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("operation_condition", "productlisting");
            bundle.putString("catids_condition", category_id[childPosition]);
            bundle.putString("catname", category_name[childPosition]);
            bundle.putString("start_row_condition", "0");
            bundle.putString("limit_condition", "10");
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(intent);
            return false;
        }
    });
}
}
```

HomeExpandableListAdapter.java

```
public class HomeExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter 

{

    private Context context;
    private List<String> listDataHeader;
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

    public HomeExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader, HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this.listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon)
    {
        return this.listDataChild.get(this.listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.home_child_items_lay, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

        txtListChild.setTypeface(EasyFonts.robotoLight(context));

        txtListChild.setText(childText);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition)
    {
        return this.listDataChild.get(this.listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).
                size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition)
    {
        return this.listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount()
    {
        return this.listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition)
    {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.home_group_items_lay, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        ImageView img=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        lblListHeader.setTypeface(EasyFonts.robotoBold(context));

        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        if(isExpanded)
        {
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_remove_grey_36pt_2x);
        }
        if(!isExpanded)
        {
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_add_grey_36pt_2x);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds()
    {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The above code works for the time, but reduces the app performance. How can I use the Asynctask class to run all that processing in the background and just create the expandable listview without overloading the ui thread.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `run()` on Thread directly just executes the code synchronously (in the same thread), just like a normal method call. you must use `start()` method to run in background.

so change following method :

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    category_id = Arrays.copyOf(category.getCategoryId(), category.getCategoryId().length);
                    category_name = Arrays.copyOf(category.getCategoryName(), category.getCategoryName().length);
                    parent_id = Arrays.copyOf(category.getParentId(), category.getParentId().length);
                }
            }).run();
```

to :

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    category_id = Arrays.copyOf(category.getCategoryId(), category.getCategoryId().length);
                    category_name = Arrays.copyOf(category.getCategoryName(), category.getCategoryName().length);
                    parent_id = Arrays.copyOf(category.getParentId(), category.getParentId().length);
                }
            }).start();
```

> Q: What's the difference between a
>   thread's start() and run() methods?
>
> A: The separate start() and run() methods in the Thread class provide
>   two ways to create threaded programs.
>   The start() method starts the
>   execution of the new thread and calls
>   the run() method. The start() method
>   returns immediately and the new thread
>   normally continues until the run()
>   method returns.
>
> The Thread class' run() method does nothing, so sub-classes should
>   override the method with code to
>   execute in the second thread. If a
>   Thread is instantiated with a Runnable
>   argument, the thread's run() method
>   executes the run() method of the
>   Runnable object in the new thread
>   instead.
>
> Depending on the nature of your threaded program, calling the Thread
>   run() method directly can give the
>   same output as calling via the start()
>   method, but in the latter case the
>   code is actually executed in a new
>   thread.

if you want implement `AsyncTask` please see [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22595659/android-asynctask-prevent-ui-from-freezing/22596071#22596071)

Comment: ok, i actually tried that, but how can i know when to setAdapter(). When will i know the thread has completed its tasks

Comment: you can't, you can use AsyncTask class for clean code, but you can use handler or runOnUiThread after doing work in back thread and update ui in thread

Comment: ok, so i can create better performance by just changing run() to start() and calling the prepareListData() and setAdapter() inside a runOnUiThread?

Comment: yes @user2132383. you are right, but this is not better performance than AsyncTask,( i don't know witch one has better performance actually ). but start has `better` than `run` as i said in my answer.

Comment: Didn't work :( All I did was change run() to start and added runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                prepareListData();
                setAdapter();
            }
        });

Comment: And I still get the error, Skipping frames... i dont get it

Comment: any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84743/discussion-between-user2132383-and-shayan-pourvatan).

Answer (score 0):

You can extend AsyncTask class to implement your background process.

```
public class YourLongTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    @Override 
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
      //run some long operation here on background
      return "return some value to post execute function. change type based on your needs";
    } 

    @Override 
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      // update your view here after on main thread after you have done long task
    } 
  }
```

You can call it like this

```
YourLongTask task = new YourLongTask().execute();
```

Information about `AsyncTask` parameters.

```
android.os.AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>
```

> Params, the type of the parameters sent to the task upon execution.
>
> Progress, the type of the progress units published during the
>   background computation.
>
> Result, the type of the result of the background computation.

Comment: The api call will be returning a String[] so do i need to make a seperate model call and create arraylist<HomeModel> to use as the return from doinBackground()

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean by that but you could put AsyncTask class within your Home (Activity) class. This way you can access your Home class variables within doInBackground and fill them with data you get from API call.